# Setting up Nginx - Nginx placing upstream name in URL

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

Why is nginx is nginx placing the upstream name in the redirected URL?

This is my `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
   worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    upstream servs {
         server facebook.com;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
              proxy_pass http://servs;
        }
    }
}
```

When I access the port 80, I get:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> servs.facebook.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

Why is it placing "**servs.**" before **facebook.com**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the `Host` header in the upstream request, so `nginx` constructs a value from the `proxy_pass` directive. As you are using an `upstream` block, this value is the name of the `upstream` block, rather than the name of the server you are trying to access.

If you are using an `upstream` block, it may be advisable to set the `Host` header explicitly:

```
proxy_set_header Host example.com;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for more.

Comment: How to dynamically put `example.com`? If upstream has multiple servers inside it say example1.com, example2.com etc,  then I can't just hardcode example1.com always right?

Comment: `proxy_set_header` can also be used with a variable. For example use `proxy_set_header Host $host;` if the reverse proxy is essentially transparent.